# Disminuir en 1 a cada elemento de una lista

Tags: python, lista, sintaxis

Tengo la siguiente lista:

```
a = [5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Necesito conseguir que todos los valores de mi lista disminuyan en 1 y me quede algo así:

```
a = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Aún estoy entendiendo la sintaxis en listas, python es mi primer lenguaje de programación, agradezco la retroalimentación, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te adjunto dos módulos

LLENADO DEL ARRAY

```
a = []
for i in range(5, 11):
    a.append(i)
```

VALORES DE LA LISTA DISMINUIDOS EN 1

```
k = 0
for i in a:
    a[k] -= 1
    k+=1
```

PUEDES VER EL RESULTADO AL HACER

```
print(a)
```

Comment: Lo de definir la lista vacía tal como lo indicas me resultó más práctico en base a lo que deseaba realizar, muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Answer (score 0):

En **Python**, para realizar operaciones sobre los elementos de cualquier lista, debes considerar estos de forma individual, es decir, de alguna forma tienes que iterar sobre cada uno. Un ciclo explicito como el `for elemento in lista` es una forma, pero también puedes usar comprensión de listas para "entender" la lista original como la resta de cada elemento:

```
[elemento - 1 for elemento in a]
```

o también puedes usar `map` y una función anónima para restar cada elemento:

```
map(lambda elemento:elemento-1, a)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su aporte, tendré muy en cuenta su método para programar,  lo de definir una lista vacía también puede ser otra solución ahora que caigo en cuenta, saludos cordiales.